# How to extract content between double curly braces with nested curly braces

Tags: javascript, string, parsing

I would like to parse the string and get the matches like this:

```js
var string = `{{type|equal:'user','This is a {{type}}','{{type}} not authorized to perform "{{current_action}}" action'}}`;
```

Desired output:

```js
[
    {
        match: '{{type|equal:'user','This is a {{type}}','{{type}} not authorized to perform "{{current_action}}" action'}}',
        key: 'type',
    },
    {
        match: '{{type}}',
        key: 'type'
    },
    {
        match: '{{current_action}}',
        key: 'current_action'
    }
]
```

This is what I have tried:

```js
var string = `{{type|equal:'user','This is a {{type}}','{{type}} not authorized to perform "{{current_action}}" action'}}`;
var regex = RegExp('{{(.*?)}}', 'g');
var match;
var matches = [];

while ((match = regex.exec(string)) !== null) {
    matches.push({match: match[0], key: match[1]});
}

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try smth like https://regex101.com/

Something like below should work

```
var matches = string.match(/{{\w+}}/g)
```

Comment: It's not giving the desired output.